# Angular json mapping ngInit

Tags: json, angular, typescript, mapping, ng

I need mapping my json in Angular. I tried many codes and my own also but nothing works and I dont know why.

```
{
"Id":1
"Name" : "nba"
"League":{
"Id": 329
"Title": "nba"}
"Teams": { "home": {
"id":1
"Name": atlanta
....

}....etc.
```

It is example because I wrote it on mobile. Please help me. Thank you

I just need to mapping this json but I am not sure why it is not working

Comment: You need translate json to class? use this tool https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript

Comment: I tried also this also by myself my own interface but nothing works

Comment: we need more info

Comment: I need read json in service on ngInit and also mapping json like is above example with categories. Mockable I use for external demo http json. Angular is latest. I tried many codes from many people also mine and doesnt work and I dont understand why. I also tried from local storage but if I use local storage its gonna just read first category and another not. Can someone help with it？

Comment: can you create an example in https://codepen.io/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, sorry, this is a poorly constructed question with no details to really help anyone...

However, I'm in my helpful phase of SO usage, so here's some JSON primer stuff for you to try.

You say JSON in your code, I assume you don't really mean constructing an object like this?

```js
const someObj = {'id': 1, 'Name':'asdf'};
```

And more you mean you have a `.json` file, presumably in your `/assets` directory somewhere, or even from a url, and you want to load it?

E.g. `myfile.json`:

```json
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "nba",
  "League": {
    "Id": 329
    "Title": "nba"
  },
  "Teams": {
    "home": {
      "id": 1,
      "Name": "atlanta"
    },
    "away": { ... }
  }
}
```

To read JSON directly into your classes, you can do a couple of things:

You can import the `HttpClientJsonpModule` into your app...

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientJsonpModule,
        ... etc
```

And then in your code you can read your json data from a url (here's a Google maps initialisation example):

```js
const sub = this.httpClient.jsonp(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${this.options.apiKey}`, 'callback')
        .subscribe(
            () => {
                this._mapReady = true;
                sub?.unsubscribe();
                this.ready();
            },
            (err) => {
                console.error('Failed to load map: ', err);
                this._mapReady = false;
                sub?.unsubscribe();
            }
        );
```

Or just via normal HTTP request - just request your own file. Standard GET request already tries to deserialise for you:

```js
const sub = this.httpClient.get('/assets/data/myJsonFile.json')
    .subscribe((data: MyJsonType) => {
        sub.unsubscribe();
        console.log('Read json data as object: ', data);
    });
```

Or you can directly pull out from local json files in your assets (assuming you want static references and not use any kind of API requests or dynamic content):

1. Make sure you have `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in your `tsconfig.json` file.
2. Hit your file:

```js
import myJsonData from '../assets/data/myJsonFile.json';

...

public get jsonData(): MyJsonDataType { return myJsonData; }
```

Or you have it as a string somewhere? Then you can use `JSON.parse` to turn it into an object...

```js
const jsonString = `{"id":1,"Name":"asdf"...}`;

public get jsonData(): MyJsonDataType { return JSON.parse(this.jsonString); }
```

One thing in common, especially given then name `Type`Script, is relevant typing.
Note: That includes relevant capitalisation of your properties to exactly match the json keys. `id` !== `Id`.

```js
export interface Team {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  // ...
}

export interface League {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  // ...
}

export interface GameTeams {
  home: Team;
  away: Team;
}

export interface Game {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  league: League;
  teams: GameTeams;
}
```

Now your stuff can read nicely, with types, from local asset json files, for example:

```js
import gameJson from '../assets/games/123.json';

public get gameData(): Game { return gameJson; }
```

Comment: If it helped sort your issue, feel free to mark it as an accepted answer.